# cannot sum rows that match a regular expression in pandas / python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I can find the number of rows in a column in a pandas dataframe that do NOT follow a pattern but not the number of rows that follow the very same pattern!

This works:

`df.report_date.apply(lambda x: (not re.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}', x))).sum()`

This does not: removing 'not' does not tell me how many rows match but raises a TypeError. Any idea why that would be the case?

`df.report_date.apply(lambda x: (re.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}', x))).sum()`

Comment: Could you add some data i.e. the input you use and your expected outcome?!

Comment: try `df.report_date.str.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}').sum()` and `df.report_date.str.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}').__neg__().sum()`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
       report_date=[
           '2001-02-04',
           '2016-11-12',
           '1-1-1999',
           '02-28-2012',
           '1995-09-30'
        ]
    ))
df
```

[image]

---

```
regex = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}'
print('does match:    {}\ndoesn\'t match: {}'.format(
        df.report_date.str.match(regex).sum(),
        df.report_date.str.match(regex).__neg__().sum()
    ))

does match:    3
doesn't match: 2
```

---

**or**

```
regex = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}'
df.groupby(df.report_date.str.match(regex)).size()

report_date
False    2
True     3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the match function does not return True when it matches, it returns a match object. Pandas cannot add this match object because it is not an integer value. The reason you get a sum when you are using 'not' is because it returns a boolean value of True, which pandas can sum the True value and return a number.

Comment: One way of dealing would be to convert them into boolean values, like `df.report_date.apply(lambda x: bool((re.match(r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}', x)))).sum()` which could then be applicable to both cases.